# Google map stops working after clicking and moving mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have following code that has two buttons, one to show a map and the other to hide it and show a paragraph. The problem is that first time I open the page it shows the map but as soon as I try to move it to find the selected positions it stops showing the map.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/dwkL3d59/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>


</head>

<body>

        <div id="myDiv" class="col-md-4 hidden-xs"
            style="padding-left: 7px; background-color: white;">

            <div class="row"
                style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 36px; background-color: white;">

                <div id="hideMap" class="col-md-5" onClick="hideMap()">Hide</div>
                <div id="showMap" class="col-md-5" onClick="populateMap()">Show</div>
            </div>

            <div id="myMap" style="width: 380px; height: 400px"></div>
            <div id="para"><p>This is it</p></div>
        </div>



<script>


    function hideMap() {
        $("#myMap").hide();
        $("#para").show();
    }

    function populateMap() {
        $("#para").hide();
        $("#myMap").show();
    }
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var pinColor = "FE7569";
    function pinImage(imagenum) {
        return image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="
                        + imagenum + "|" + pinColor);
    }

    function initialize() {
        var centreLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(37.9908372,23.7383394);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom : 13,
            center : centreLoc,
            disableDefaultUI : true,
            mapTypeControlOptions : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'),
                mapOptions);
        hideMap();
        var results = [ [ 'Pos1', 37.9908372,23.7383394 ],
                [ 'Pos2', 37.89,23.7383394 ] ];
        processResults(results);
    }

    function processResults(results) {
        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
        $("#marker-container").empty();
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var place = results[i][0];
            var placeLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(results[i][2], results[i][3]);
            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                title : place,
                position : placeLoc,
                icon : pinImage(i + 1)
            });

            markers.push(marker);
            var description = $("<div class='marker-description'><image class='marker' src='" + marker.icon.url + "'></image><span class='place'>"
                    + place + "</span>");
            $("#marker-container").append(description);
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Before (Once the demo is loaded)

[image]

After (Try to find an address on the map)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "move" the map? Moving the HTML code across the DOM? Or panning the map with the mouse?

Comment: @JeremyThille panning the map with the mouse

Comment: Could you try and make a Fiddle? I tried with your code, but I can't manage to have a map show up : https://jsfiddle.net/n2sfpLca/1/

Comment: [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2sfpLca/2/) [but I don't see the issue]

Comment: @JeremyThille demo is added to the question

Comment: @geocodezip yeah it does not stop working,however it is not showing the two selected locations on the map. Question is also updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the 'resize' event on the map after it is displayed, then set the center once it has a size:

```
function populateMap() {
    $("#para").hide();
    $("#myMap").show();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
    map.setCenter(centreLoc);
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwkL3d59/2/)

code snippet (removed `signed_in=true`, doesn't play well in SO code snippets):

```js
function hideMap() {
        $("#myMap").hide();
        $("#para").show();
    }

    function populateMap() {
        $("#para").hide();
        $("#myMap").show();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
        map.setCenter(centreLoc);
    }
    var map;
    var centreLoc;
    var markers = [];
    var pinColor = "FE7569";
    function pinImage(imagenum) {
        return image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld="
                        + imagenum + "|" + pinColor);
    }

    function initialize() {
        centreLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(37.9908372,23.7383394);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom : 13,
            center : centreLoc,
            disableDefaultUI : true,
            mapTypeControlOptions : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'),
                mapOptions);
        hideMap();
        var results = [ [ 'Pos1', 37.9908372,23.7383394 ],
                [ 'Pos2', 37.89,23.7383394 ] ];
        processResults(results);
    }

    function processResults(results) {
        for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
            marker.setMap(null);
        }
        markers = [];
        $("#marker-container").empty();
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var place = results[i][0];
            var placeLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(results[i][1], results[i][2]);
            // Create a marker for each place.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                title : place,
                position : placeLoc,
                icon : pinImage(i + 1)
            });

            markers.push(marker);
            var description = $("<div class='marker-description'><image class='marker' src='" + marker.icon.url + "'></image><span class='place'>"
                    + place + "</span>");
            $("#marker-container").append(description);
        }
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" class="col-md-4 hidden-xs"
            style="padding-left: 7px; background-color: white;">

            <div class="row"
                style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 36px; background-color: white;">

                <div id="hideMap" class="col-md-5" onClick="hideMap()">Hide</div>
                <div id="showMap" class="col-md-5" onClick="populateMap()">Show</div>
            </div>

            <div id="myMap" style="width: 380px; height: 400px"></div>
            <div id="para"><p>This is it</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

sorry for late response
if you mind please this one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-social/4.2.1/bootstrap-social.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv" class="col-md-4 hidden-xs" style="padding-left: 7px; background-color: white;">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 36px; background-color: white;">
      <div id="hideMap" class="col-md-5" onClick="hideMap()">Hide</div>
      <div id="showMap" class="col-md-5" onClick="populateMap()">Show</div>
    </div>
    <div id="myMap" style="width: 380px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <div id="para"><p>This is it</p></div>
  </div>
<script>
  function hideMap() {
    $("#myMap").css('display', 'none');
    $("#para").css('display', 'block');
  }
  function populateMap() {
    $("#para").hide();
    $("#myMap").show();
  }
  var map;
  var markers = [];
  var pinColor = "FE7569";
  function pinImage(imagenum) {
    return image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=" + imagenum + "|" + pinColor);
  }
  function initialize() {
    var centreLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(37.9908372,23.7383394);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom : 10,
      center : centreLoc,
      disableDefaultUI : true,
      mapTypeControlOptions : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), mapOptions);
    var results = [ [ 'Pos1', 37.9908372,23.7383394 ], [ 'Pos2', 37.89,23.7383394 ] ];
    processResults(results);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
      hideMap();
    });
  }
  function processResults(results) {
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];
    $("#marker-container").empty();
    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var place = results[i][0];
      var placeLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(results[i][1], results[i][2]);
      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map : map,
        title : place,
        position : placeLoc,
        icon : pinImage(i + 1)
      });
      markers.push(marker);
      var description = $("<div class='marker-description'><image class='marker' src='" + marker.icon.url + "'></image><span class='place'>" + place + "</span>");
        $("#marker-container").append(description);
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put wrong style

```
<div id="myMap"></div>
<div id="para" style="width: 380px; height: 400px;"><p>This is it</p></div>
```

to this one

```
<div id="myMap" style="width: 380px; height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="para"><p>This is it</p></div>
```